# How to work with remote Git repository on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I managed to create a repository on GitHub with a few of my projects. Now I'd like to do some work on those projects and get the changes back on to GitHub so people can see them.

Can someone clearly and explicitly explain to me how to properly do the following:

1. Create a local version of the remote repository on my computer
2. Start making and tracking changes of the local copy
3. When I'm done making changes merge them back into my remote repository